# Excel Doc Sum row b where row a in between dates

Tags: excel, date, google-docs

I have a google spreadsheet having data as below

```
Date           SomeVal  
Aug 01, 2013         1  
Aug 02, 2013         5
```

And so on. I want to have another sheet with Monthly grouping as follows(This is what I want in the end but unable to get here)

```
Month     Total  
Apr 2013    200  
May 2013    300
```

I tried following but could not get correct result

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A,ʺ> Aug 1, 2013ʺ) //Returns SUM(B:B) as all dates are above Aug 1 2013  
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!B:B,Sheet1!A:A,ʺ< Jun 1, 2014ʺ) //Returns 0 which is wrong
```

This is what I expected to get

- sum for which date > Aug 2013
- sum for which date < Jun 2014

My date format is Mon DD, YYYY

Any idea Where I am wrong

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more of your data. Check my answer below, hopefully it will give you a bit of help.

Comment: @BenBlack Thanks mate. It worked, any idea what is wrong in my query, still unable to figure out that, is it that `string unable to get formatted to date for comparison.`

Comment: That could very well be it, I'm not sure how Excel deals with references in formulas and how it converts them to be comparable to other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This format works for me

**Raw Data in Sheet2**

```
(Column A)  (Column B)
Date        Val
----------- ---------
7/1/2013    1
7/2/2013    2
7/3/2013    3
7/4/2013    4
```

And so on and so forth up until 2/9/2016 (as long as they are date values you can format them however you want)

**Summed Data in Sheet1**

```
(Column A) (Column B)
Month      Total
---------- ---------
Jul 2013   496  
Aug 2013   1457
Sep 2013   2325
Oct 2013   3348
Nov 2013   4155
```

So on and so forth for each month that I want, using this formula. Each month is formatted as MMM YYYY, and the date is the first of the month (7/1/2013, 8/1/2013, etc...)

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet2!$B:$B,Sheet2!$A:$A,">="&Sheet1!$A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,"<"&Sheet1!$A3)
```

This says

- Sum the range in Sheet 2 Column B where:

  - The date in column A of that row is greater than the first of the month supplied
  - The date in column A of that row is less than the first of the month afterwards